# Long IDs on Bigquery are importing into excel using scientific notation, don't import correct number

Tags: sql, excel, google-bigquery

I am running a very basic query to export a list of IDs. However, when I go to export that list to a CSV, excel converts the IDs to scientific notation and the IDs are no longer accurate (last digit is replaced with 0).

```
SELECT
  Subscription_id
FROM
` ds.sites`,
  unnest(SubscriptionIds)subscription_id
```

Any ideas for modifying the query so that it exports correctly? I tried using concat() to add quotes around the id (bc excel should recognize quotes), but it isn't printing correctly:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(''', Subscription_id, ''') as Subscription_ID
FROM
` ds.sites`,
  unnest(SubscriptionIds)subscription_id


Row Subscription_ID  
1   , Subscription_id,   
2   , Subscription_id,   
3   , Subscription_id,   
4   , Subscription_id,   
5   , Subscription_id,
```

[Excel export -- all numbers end in 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpTf1.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should just change the way you getting resulting CSV file into Excel!
Instead of opening file with Excel  - do below:

1 - Open Excel, with empty book
 2 - Choose in Menu/Toolbar: Data > From Text
 3 - Select your csv file
 4 - complete Import Dialog
 5 - In step 3  - for respective columns  - specify Text format

Done

[image]

You will get all digits in place
In above "example" first field was SELECT'ed as STRING and second one as INT64

Answer (score 0):

In Bigquery, `''', Subscription_id, '''` is a "triple-quoted" string, in which you just get a plain string of everything between the triple quotes.

Try:

```
CONCAT("\"", Subscription_id, "\"")
```